# python - Change multiple files of same extensions

Tags: python

I am running a script that would change the contents inside a file with extension hgx.

E.g. test.hgx

Now, I have multiple files with extension hgx and I would like to run this same script for all the files (with extension hgx).

My current script looks like:

```
file_name = "test.hgx"

x = open(file_name,'r')
....(and so on)
```

Is it possible to use something like:

```
file_name = "*.hgx"

x = open(file_name,'r')
....
```

So that the script runs for all the files with extension hgx. Any workaround or method to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`glob.iglob()`](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html#glob.iglob):

```
for filename in glob.iglob("*.hgx"):
    with open(filename) as f:
        # process file f here
```

Comment: Thanks. But this does not seem to accept all the files at same time,neither one after the other. Any other ideas on how can go ahead to modify all the hgx files ?

Comment: @user: "This does not seem to accept all the files at same time, neither one after the other." No idea what your problem is -- you need to be more explicit in what you expect and what happens instead.